# Install - SharePoint server - SQL and SPN

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, active-directory, kerberos, spn

I have a question about installing SQL server and a SP2016 development farm. I can install both but my boss asked me questions about installing SPN (Service Principal Name) in the AD. But I don't know why and how an SPN is linked with SQL and SharePoint.

I've done some research on the web and got some terms "Kerberos" but I installed SharePoint with NTLM. Help me understand why SPNs would be useful in this case.

Comment: @thriggle :Thank for editing. But i need to precise that it's for a developping farm and not a production farm. Develloping farm isn't publish for customers instead of production's one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What is a Service Principal Name?

The SPN represents the service entry point into your SQL server for clients to find (using DNS) when they will be using Kerberos authentication.

SPNs are written as a service followed by the fully-qualified DNS name of the IP host the service is running on, (and sometimes optionally, appended with the Kerberos realm name appended to the end). For example if your SQL server were named 'sqlserver1' and your AD domain name was 'acme.com' would be written as: *MSSQLsvc/sqlserver1.acme.com*.

The SPN itself is found inside the Kerberos database, and clients during the authentication process reach out to DNS to find the IP target host and the Kerberos database (KDC) holding the service principal, grab a Kerberos service ticket from the KDC and use that to single sign-on authenticate to the server running on the target service named in the SPN.

#### Configuring SPNs

In AD, in the properties of the computer object representing your SQL server, you will add the SPN, and optionally configure Kerberos delegation for that service.  You could optionally add the SPN to a user account running the SQL service in AD instead.

In your scenario, Kerberos should actually be the primary authentication method, with NTLM used only as a fallback.  If you setup up DNS, AD, Kerberos delegation and the target server correctly, you should never have to fallback to NTLM.  With SharePoint, you would use Kerberos to SSO into SharePoint, and then you could optionally allow Kerberos delegation for that same user account to be able to run SQL statements own the SQL DB server as themselves.

None of this is for the faint of heart, and I have actually not setup this precise scenario myself, I just know the underlying concepts; instead my experience is mainly setting up Kerberos SSO to Active Directory authentication to web applications running on Linux platforms.  But you asked what an SPN was for and that's what I've answered.

#### Further Reading

I googled and found this link for you for actually setting up your scenario, it talks about configuring SharePoint with Active Directory with SQL server using Kerberos delegation:  [Plan for Kerberos authentication in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806870.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: my service account for SQL is : SQL_svc. By using a command i would write :   setspn -a MSSQLsvc/serversql1.acme.com acme\SQL_svc ???

Comment: Run it like this:   setspn -s MSSQLsvc/serversql1.acme.com SQL_svc

Comment: @Thriggle has improved the look and flow of my answer (thanks!).  Kevin, pls let us know if this is resolved with SPN command I suggested.